# sum elements of dataframe column based on another column result (which is a string)

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe that returns an ACTION.  Depending on the ACTION it will increase or decrease the BALANCE based on the % change in the CHANGE column.
if the action is BH or BC the BALANCE will change by the % in the CHANGE column
BALANCE is not changed on B or SIT days
Example of what my dataframe currently looks like is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ACTION'] = ('SIT','BC', 'BH', 'BH', 'BH', 'BH', 'B', 'SIT', 'SIT')
df['CHANGE'] = (0.02, -0.02, 0.17, -0.01, 0.05, -0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01)


df = df[::-1]
conditions = [
    df['ACTION'].eq('BC'),
    df['ACTION'].eq('BH'),
    df['ACTION'].eq('B'),
    df['ACTION'].eq('SIT')
]
choices = [df['CHANGE'], df['CHANGE'], 0, 0]
df['GAIN/LOSS'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
df = df[::-1]

df.loc[8, 'BALANCE'] = 100.0000

for i in df.index[::-1][:-1]:
        df.loc[i - 1, 'BALANCE'] = df.loc[i, 'BALANCE']  + (df.loc[i, 'BALANCE'] * df.loc[i - 1, 'GAIN/LOSS'])

print(df)
```

above code leads to following output:

```
 ACTION  CHANGE  GAIN/LOSS     BALANCE

0    SIT    0.02       0.00  116.805289

1     BC   -0.02      -0.02  116.805289

2     BH    0.17       0.17  119.189070

3     BH   -0.01      -0.01  101.871000

4     BH    0.05       0.05  102.900000

5     BH   -0.02      -0.02   98.000000

6      B    0.02       0.00  100.000000

7    SIT    0.03       0.00  100.000000

8    SIT    0.01       0.00  100.000000
```

I however am looking for some code where the BALANCE is only updated on a BC row and this row sums the net change that occurred between the first BH after the B and BC
Basically I would like my datatframe to look like as follows:
On row 1 the BALANCE column sums up the net change between BC and the first BH which is 17% and output would look like as follows:

```
 ACTION  CHANGE  GAIN/LOSS     BALANCE

0    SIT    0.02       0.00  117.000000

1     BC   -0.02      -0.02  117.000000

2     BH    0.17       0.17  100.000000

3     BH   -0.01      -0.01  100.000000

4     BH    0.05       0.05  100.000000

5     BH   -0.02      -0.02  100.000000

6      B    0.02       0.00  100.000000

7    SIT    0.03       0.00  100.000000

8    SIT    0.01       0.00  100.000000
```

Comment: Can you maybe tell us more about your real world problem? Why do you iterate backwards, but have a boundary condition for `BALANCE` on the first `BH` in forward direction? Why doesn't the balance change in your desired output on the other `BC` and `BH` columns, contrary to your description in the 1st paragraph?

Comment: It is iterated backwards as in my real code I am pulling price data from a trading exchange and the latest data is row 0.  I then perform some calculations that are based on say the next 1000 rows. Maybe there is a better way to do this but I am a noob

Comment: My first paragraph explains what I currently am performing however the second paragraph explains what I desire

Comment: My desire is not to have the BALANCE change on BH rows rather only the BC row which sums the current BC row and the previous BH rows that are underneath.  For a BC row to appear it can only happen if first there is a B occurring

Comment: What you describe sounds like it shouldn't be `117` in row 1, but (from 5 to 1 upwards): `100 * 0.98 * 1.05 * 0.99 * 1.17 = 119.19` - exactly what you've got in row 2 in your first output. The net change is `19.19%` up till row 2, not `17%` (or `16.81%` if you include the `BC`-column)